# Processing huge amounts of data parallel, equally divided into available cores

Tags: node.js, multithreading, brute-force

The story is that I have a pretty heavy function, which accepts 4 parameters, all of them are percentages. What I'm trying to achieve is to get what are the 4 percentage values that are returning the best possible result. Each parameter is tried from `0.00`, all the way up to `1.00`, with `0.01` steps, so 100 possibilities for each. Because I have 4, it means 100.000.000 possibilities.

I've calculated that with my poor Macbook Pro would take approximately 14 hours to calculate the result. It seemed obvious to rent a 96 core VM with huge memory, but the calculating speed was approx the same. After some research I realised that it doesn't matter how many cores I calculate with, as Node will use one anyway (it's not a bad thing to understand the background, not just write code, right).

From the research I met with *clusters*, where multiple cores can be used to do things in parallel, what I'm still struggling with to understand how it will work, but my idea to start with synchronous style, then split the combinations into `numberOfCpus` pieces, and give each core it's part of the work, then when it all finished (like a `Promise.all()`), go back to synchronous, and do whatever with the array of results.

The only thing I have concerns about is probably clustering is perfect for "cloning a server's APIs", where they are independent from each other, but in my case they are sort of in relation, and will do different things.

However, just a quick example of what I'm thinking of:

```js
import { heavyProcessingFunction } from '..';
import cluster from 'cluster';
import { cpus } from 'os';

export handler = async () => {
  const percs = Array.from(Array(100), (_, i) => (i + 1) / 100);
  const combinations = (
    percs.map((a) =>
      percs.map((b) =>
        percs.map((c) =>
          percs.map((d) => [a, b, c, d]),
        ),
      ),
    )
    .flat(3)
  );
  const numberOfCpus = cpus().length;
  const elementsPerPart = Math.floor(combinations.length / numberOfCpus);

  const chunks = [...Array(numberOfCpus)].map((e, i) => {
      if (i === numberOfCpus - 1) {
          return combinations;
      }
      return combinations.splice(0, elementsPerPart);
  });

  //some magic with clusters to run each element in the array below in parallel
  const resultOfEachCore = await Promise.all(
    chunks.map(combinations => (
      clusterMagic(
        heavyProcessingFunction(...combinations)
      )
    )
  );

  //after finished, process them
  resultOfEachCore//...
}
```

Comment: Is your `heavyProcessingFunction` a linear combination of the four parameters or a [differentiable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function)? If so, you may want to look at an approach like [Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) or [Linear Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). (I haven't used it but [optimization-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/optimization-js) may help you.)

Comment: Wouldn't like to pollute the question with details what `heavyProcessingFunction` is, but it runs through Apple's daily stock performance 10 years back, and those 4 parameters control when to sell, how much, and when to buy, how much. Just for fun

Comment: given what you've said I'd also suggest looking into MCMC algorithms for exploring the space.  plotting 1e8 points basically isn't going to happen, so presumably you're just after some best/worst area and MC algorithms can be set up to efficiently target these.  I've used these in stats models to target distributions with thousands of parameters, which is basically impossible with your exhaustive grid-search

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really about multithreading, but it might compute your solution more quickly.

I looked at [optimization-js](https://github.com/optimization-js/optimization-js) and it doesn't seem to require any special properties about the function used. Since you're looking for a maximum, you may want to negate the output of your heavyProcessingFunction before passing it to the minimizer. With 10000 iterations as written below, it takes less than a second to run.

```js
const O = window.optimjs;

// An arbitrary function. X is an array of 4 numbers, because `space` has 4 dimentsions
function heavyProcessingFunction(X) {
  const dotProduct = X.map(xi => xi * xi).reduce((acc, xi) => acc + xi);
  return -dotProduct; // algorithm minimizes instead of maximizing
}

const range = new O.Real(0, 1);
const space = new O.Space([range, range, range, range]);
const numIterations = 10000;

var solution = O.rs_minimize(heavyProcessingFunction, space, numIterations);
console.log("Best points:", solution.best_x);
console.log("Value at best points", solution.best_y);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/optimization-js@latest/dist/optimization.js"></script>
```